# Does Cramer Rao bound depend on the sample size?

Tags: sample-size, cramer-rao

I have a confusion regarding sample size and CRB.

CRB can be found for any estimator, even when it is biased. There are formulas to compute a "biased-CRB". There are also papers suggesting how to compute the biased-CRB when the bias gradients are not tractable.

However, there are some estimators that are asymptotically unbiased. So, when there are a finite number of samples, the estimators are indeed biased (regardless of the fact that the bias gradient is known).

So, can we say that there exists a CRB for an estimator for any number of samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case of a scalar estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ with expected value $\psi_n(\theta) \equiv \mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}_n|\theta)$ and Fisher information $I_n(\theta)$, the [Cramér–Rao lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) is:

$$\mathbb{V}(\hat{\theta}_n)\geqslant \frac{(\psi_n'(\theta))^2}{I_n(\theta)}.$$

The general bound formula is valid for any sample size so long as it is sufficient for the estimator and its expectation to exist (which usually occurs at a low sample size).  At points where $\psi_n'(\theta)=0$ (i.e., where the expectation function is at a critical point) the bound is zero and so it "exists" only in the trivial sense of confirming that the variance is non-negative.  (For an estimator that is a constant this will hold over the entire parameter range and so the bound becomes trivial, but also equal to the true estimator variance of zero.)  Typically, both the expectation function $\psi_n$ and the Fisher information $I_n$ depend on the sample size $n$ so the bound will usually vary with $n$.

So yes, setting aside the case where the sample size is so low that the estimator or its expectation do not exist (and perhaps also setting aside the trivial case of a constant estimator), we can say that there exists a CRB for an estimator for any number of samples.

Comment: $\exists\forall$ or $\forall\exists$? I think you mean the former but am not sure.

Comment: Subject to the listed caveats, for all $n$ there exists a bound (or to put it another way, there exists a bound that is a function of $n$).